# Http file transfer and folders

Tags: http, multipart

I would like to know if it's possible using an HTTP file transfer to also have the receiving server create a folder for the incoming files?

For example, I'd like to transfer 5 files, 4 of which should end up in a folder.
Unfortunately I cannot use zip, but I know the receiving servers will all be on Windows.

Is this possible as part of the file transfer?

If not, is it possible to send some kind of indicator/message to the receiver to create a folder, write the next X files into it, then write Y files outside the folder (at the same level) ?

Here's another post of mine where I show the transfer code I'm using: [How to post ByteArrayOutputStream via http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42909244/how-to-post-bytearrayoutputstream-via-http)

Comment: Its unclear what your asking; its the responsibility of the code that receives the HTTP request to handle/write the files - it can do whatever it likes.  A multipart upload can contain standard (non-file)  values that you can set to whatever you like if thats what your looking for.

Comment: @AlexK. - I'll try to clarify - I'd like to know how to transfer a group of files so that a new folder is created on the receiving end and the files are located in that folder.  I'm assuming from your response that I should 1) Include some kind of message/indication that the receiver should create a folder and then 2) Put the received files into that folder.

Comment: OK I've resolved the issue by using request parameters and having my servlet do the rest.